# Javascript reference shortcuts within object (do they take up space?)

Tags: javascript, memory-management

I have a javascript object with very large properties like so (imagine that "large-object X" are complex and large javascript objects):

```
let myObject = {
    primary: { "large-object A" },
    secundary: [ {"large-object B"}, {"large-object C"}, {"large-object D"} ],
}
```

In some scenario's I just need to have `myObject.primary`, but sometimes I don't care about the primary/secundary distinction, and I want to loop over **all** objects. Now, I did some tests, and I seem to be able to create a new property, which I call "`all`", that can *by-reference* point to all the objects in primary and secundary:

```
let myObject = {
    primary: { "large-object A" },
    secundary: [ {"large-object B"}, {"large-object C"}, {"large-object D"} ],
    all: []
}

if (!_.isEmpty(myObject.primary)) {
    myObject.all.push(myObject.primary)
}
myObject.all.push(...myObject.secundary) // spread = shallow copy
```

The thing I am not sure about right now is if the memory usage by this object is not going up by adding references. My common sense logic tells me that there should be no need, but I worry if there are garbage collectors, code optimizers, serializer, or whatever in the browser or VM, that perhaps still cause memory to be allocated for the "duplicated" objects.

So the question can be proposed as:

**Q. Do objects that are references to other objects within an object still take up memory (apart from the reference 'pointer' itself).**

*On a side note: I do the push of the primary, followed by the spread of the secundary so that the primary object will still be first in the resulting array, and in my scenario the primary could also just be an empty object.*

Comment: I don't think you should worry. `a = {foo: "bar"}; b = [a, a, a]` will allocate the object once and then you'd have a total of four references to it. You won't get any more than one copy of the object itself.

Comment: BTW, if you're *really* worried about memory and you happen to just want to iterate over all your objects, you can try a generator method that just gives you every object in sequence. It's one at a time, so you don't make an entirely new array that contains all your objects yet again. https://jsbin.com/jidiyos/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you spread the elements, you're not deep cloning the elements in a second level. There is not a duplication of the elements there. You can try this little simplification and see:

```
let a = { a: 1, b: 2 };
let b = [ {a: 3}, {a : 2} ];

let c = [];

c.push(...b);

console.log( c[0] === b[0] ); // true
```

Comment: Yeah I came to the same conclusion (using a different approach).. In was feeling worried because the objects are big-ish and many, so I need to be certain. A second-opinion to ease my mind. :-) Thanks

Comment: @svenema If that solution works for you, please mark it as the solution.